# Find the frames which are similar in two videos

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find out the audio lag during a video call (in Zoom/ Google Meet). The r goal is to measure the lag in audio and video in the output (meeting attender's side).
For that, I have two video :

1. Vid1 (recording at presenter's side).
2. Vid2 (recording at attender's side).

Both the recordings can be started at any time during the meeting.
Now since I am comparing the videos, I need to find out the common frame between two videos. So that if I play the videos side by side, they should play in sync.

Since V1 and V2 is not same (V2 maybe pixelated), so how can two videos be compared to find the common frame?

Comment: Are you assuming that the two recordings contain the exact same content (besides the pixelation problem and the start:end time)?

Comment: Yes, they should be same as they are recorded from a same meeting.

Comment: I'm no expert in the field, but I'm trying to help. Would it be useful to build a function that identifies transitions? In that way you can map each frame to a 0 or a 1 (no transition or transition) and so you can align the two videos. You don't even need to build the perfect function, it can guess correctly 40% of the time, the important thing is to keep that 40% consistent between the two videos, so for example you could count - for each frame - the percentage of the screen that differs from previous frame